# Detect content change inside cross domain iframe in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible in Vue.js (or just plain old js) to detect when an iframe (that contains content from another domain) has changed? Here is the more precise scenario:

1. I load a page that contains an iFrame with content from another domain
2. The user clicks a button (or does something) inside that iframe, which changes the content inside the iframe
3. Can I somehow detect that change?

I don't want to affect or change any of the content inside the frame, just detect that it has changed. Is this possible?

Comment: "The user clicks a button inside that iframe, which.." - is that really a good idea though? If you're listening to that event from another DOM (of the iframe), there are lot of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I actually don't care about the event. I just need to detect ANY content change inside the iframe.

Comment: I don't think you can, this would be a huge security breach. Imagine you include a facebook iframe on your website, you could access the user name and information if he's logged in...

Comment: good point. But all I really want to know is if SOMETHING changed, I don't even need to know anything specific ABOUT it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a way to make this work for my needs. I set a counter which gets updated on every onload event (which I figured out gets fired when someone submits a form inside my iframe), then make my changes to the surrounding page:

```
      const iframe = document.querySelector('#myframe')
      iframe.onload = () => {
        this.formloadCounter += 1
        console.log('iframe has been loaded:' + this.formloadCounter + ' times.')
        if (this.formloadCounter>1) { 
          //do stuff 
        }
      }
```